# median from survfit object and textConnection

Tags: r

I've used the methods of others to grab the median from a `survfit` object, namely using `textConnecton`, but I am running into a couple problems.

```
# example
library(survival)
data(cancer)

cox.ph <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ strata(I(age > 60)), data = cancer)
coxph.fit <- survfit(cox.ph, conf.type = 'log-log')

tmp <- tail(capture.output(print(coxph.fit)), length(unique(coxph.fit$strata)) + 1)
tmp <- read.table(z <- textConnection(tmp), header = TRUE)
```

Gives me this error:

Error in read.table(z <- textConnection(tmp), header = TRUE) : 
  more columns than column names

and what `tmp` looks like

```
> tmp
[1] "                  records n.max n.start events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL"
[2] "I(age > 60)=FALSE      94    94      94     64    353     268     390"
[3] "I(age > 60)=TRUE      134   134     134    101    301     239     353"
```

So I'm thinking that the problem is with the spaces in the strata and how it is read by `textConnection` Another example:

```
cox.ph <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ strata(sex), data = cancer)
coxph.fit <- survfit(cox.ph, conf.type = 'log-log')

tmp <- tail(capture.output(print(coxph.fit)), length(unique(coxph.fit$strata)) + 1)
tmp <- read.table(z <- textConnection(tmp), header = TRUE)
close(z)
```

Here, `tmp` behaves as I want:

```
> tmp
records n.max n.start events median X0.95LCL X0.95UCL
sex=1     138   138     138    112    270      210      306
sex=2      90    90      90     53    426      345      524
> tmp$median
[1] 270 426
```

So basically, is there another method or a way that I can tell `textConnection` to use multiple spaces or tab as a delimiter (if that is indeed the issue)?

I need to be able to use both methods, i.e. `strata(sex)` and `strata(I(...))`, because I am using this within a function, and the user supplies the `survfit` object.

The second problem is that (I am using Rstudio (not the problem) ) if I narrow the console window so that `tmp` is split into several more rows of output, like so

```
> tmp
      records n.max n.start
sex=1     138   138     138
sex=2      90    90      90
      events median X0.95LCL
sex=1    112    270      210
sex=2     53    426      345
      X0.95UCL
sex=1      306
sex=2      524
```

So that my final data frame after `read.table` becomes

```
> tmp
X0.95UCL
sex=1      306
sex=2      524
```

Which is obviously going to be a problem:

```
> tmp$median
NULL
```

Here, the issue is probably that the output is captured as it will be printed in the console, and I want everything regardless of how it is printed or how large the console margins are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not actually using any of the objects, but is rather doing a screen scrape of side-effects printed to the console.

The easy way:

```
options(survfit.rmean = "individual")
summary(coxph.fit)$table   # returns the whole table from survmeans
summary(coxph.fit)$table[ , "median"]
#I(age > 60)=FALSE  I(age > 60)=TRUE 
#              353               301
```

[Hitting self in head: This is now the second time I've gone through the following process needlessly. The extraction of the desired printed table is describe in `?summary.survfit`](http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3aorg.r-project.r-help%20survmean#query%3alist%3aorg.r-project.r-help%20survmean%20page:1%20mid%3aaaxrgp6t7bub6t7j%20state%3aresults) 
The hard way: If you want to get the "median"-as-object (and print it) you can high-jack the `print.survfit` function and modify it to print and return the median column of the matrix that the hidden function `survmean` creates:

```
print.survfit.median <- 
    function (x, scale = 1, digits = max(options()$digits - 4, 3), 
             print.rmean = getOption("survfit.print.rmean"),
             rmean = getOption("survfit.rmean"), 
          ...) 
{
    if (inherits(x, "survfitms")) {
        x$surv <- 1 - x$prev
        if (is.matrix(x$surv)) 
            dimnames(x$surv) <- list(NULL, x$states)
        if (!is.null(x$lower)) {
            x$lower <- 1 - x$lower
            x$upper <- 1 - x$upper
        }
    }
    if (!is.null(cl <- x$call)) {
        cat("Call: ")
        dput(cl)
        cat("\n")
    }
    omit <- x$na.action
    if (length(omit)) 
        cat("  ", naprint(omit), "\n")
    savedig <- options(digits = digits)
    on.exit(options(savedig))
    if (!missing(print.rmean) && is.logical(print.rmean) && missing(rmean)) {
        if (print.rmean) 
            rmean <- "common"
        else rmean <- "none"
    }
    else {
        if (is.null(rmean)) {
            if (is.logical(print.rmean)) {
                if (print.rmean) 
                  rmean <- "common"
                else rmean <- "none"
            }
            else rmean <- "none"
        }
        if (is.numeric(rmean)) {
            if (is.null(x$start.time)) {
                if (rmean < min(x$time)) 
                  stop("Truncation point for the mean is < smallest survival")
            }
            else if (rmean < x$start.time) 
                stop("Truncation point for the mean is < smallest survival")
        }
        else {
            rmean <- match.arg(rmean, c("none", "common", "individual"))
            if (length(rmean) == 0) 
                stop("Invalid value for rmean option")
        }
    }
    temp <- survival:::survmean(x, scale = scale, rmean)
    print(temp$matrix[ , "median"])

}s
```

Then use it:

```
> z <- print.survfit.median(coxph.fit)
Call: survfit(formula = cox.ph, conf.type = "log-log")

I(age > 60)=FALSE  I(age > 60)=TRUE 
              353               301 
> z
I(age > 60)=FALSE  I(age > 60)=TRUE 
              353               301
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you so much. Hope it wasn't too much work

Comment: It was too much work, in the sense it was unnecessary. I'm posting at the top what I should have remembered after having already gone a baroque process before in response to an R-help query.

Answer (score 0):

If @IShouldBuyABoat doesn't mind, I will just build off of his answer and tweak it slightly.

```
print.survfit.select <- function (x, vars = c('records','n.max','n.start','events','median','0.95LCL','0.95UCL'), suppress = TRUE,
                                  scale = 1, digits = max(options()$digits - 4, 3), print.rmean = getOption('survfit.print.rmean'), 
                                  rmean = getOption('survfit.rmean'), ...) {

  # usage: 
  # x     survfit object
  # vars  takes c('records','n.max','n.start','events','median','0.95LCL','0.95UCL')
  # ...   see survival:::print.survfit

  if (inherits(x, 'survfitms')) {
    x$surv <- 1 - x$prev
    if (is.matrix(x$surv)) 
      dimnames(x$surv) <- list(NULL, x$states)
    if (!is.null(x$lower)) {
      x$lower <- 1 - x$lower
      x$upper <- 1 - x$upper
    }
  }
  if (!suppress) {
    if (!is.null(cl <- x$call)) {
    cat('Call: ')
    dput(cl)
    cat('\n')
    }
  }
  omit <- x$na.action
  if (length(omit)) 
    cat('  ', naprint(omit), '\n')
  savedig <- options(digits = digits)
  on.exit(options(savedig))
  if (!missing(print.rmean) && is.logical(print.rmean) && missing(rmean)) {
    if (print.rmean) 
      rmean <- 'common'
    else rmean <- 'none'
  } else {
    if (is.null(rmean)) {
      if (is.logical(print.rmean)) {
        if (print.rmean) 
          rmean <- 'common' 
        else rmean <- 'none'
      } else rmean <- 'none'
    }
    if (is.numeric(rmean)) {
      if (is.null(x$start.time)) {
        if (rmean < min(x$time)) 
          stop('Truncation point for the mean is < smallest survival')
      }
      else if (rmean < x$start.time) 
        stop('Truncation point for the mean is < smallest survival')
    } else {
      rmean <- match.arg(rmean, c('none', 'common', 'individual'))
      if (length(rmean) == 0) 
        stop('Invalid value for rmean option')
    }
  }
  temp <- survival:::survmean(x, scale = scale, rmean)

  if (is.null(x$strata)) print(temp$matrix[vars]) 
  else print(temp$matrix[ ,vars])
}
```

so now we can

```
> print.survfit.select(coxph.fit)
Call: survfit(formula = cox.ph, conf.type = "log-log")

      records n.max n.start events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
sex=1     138   138     138    112    270     210     306
sex=2      90    90      90     53    426     345     524
> print.survfit.select(coxph.fit, vars = c('0.95LCL','median','0.95UCL'))
Call: survfit(formula = cox.ph, conf.type = "log-log")

      0.95LCL median 0.95UCL
sex=1     210    270     306
sex=2     345    426     524

> z <- print.survfit.select(coxph.fit, vars = c('median'))
Call: survfit(formula = cox.ph, conf.type = "log-log")

sex=1 sex=2 
  270   426 
> z
sex=1 sex=2 
  270   426
```

... if someone else out there finds that useful.

Thanks again!

Comment: I certainly don't mind. My work was just figuring out how the screen output was not in the returned matrix object and removing part of Terry Therneau's code and exposing an object that he ordinarily printed but did not return. Your work adds more control to that process.

Comment: wasn't working for an object with no strata. Fixed but probably wasn't the best way in terms of efficient code. Also added the suppress argument to stop the call printing